# Fundamental theorem of calculus when endpoint is an integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I have to solve the following 
$$ F(x) =\int_0^{\int_1^x \sin^{3}t\, dt} \frac{1}{1+t^{2}+\sin^{6}t}\, dt $$
using the fundamental theorem of calculus i.e I have to obtain $f(x)$ by finding $F'(x)$, so far
I tried seeing $$\int_1^x \sin^{3}t \,dt$$ as a function of $x$ but I am not sure if that is possible and haven't found a similar problem so far so I would like to have some insight on solving this kind of problem.

Comment: What do you mean you have to solve? Do you need to calculate $F$? Or differentiate $F$? And is $sen$ the $\sin(x)$ or $\sec(x)$ function?

Comment: I have to differentiate F, and yes sin = sen (sorry, spanish is my first language and I wrote sin in spanish)

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

Let 
$$G(x)= \int_0^{H(x)} \frac{1}{1+t^{2}+\sin^{6}t} \,\mathrm dt \\
H(x)=\int_1^x \sin^{3}t \,\mathrm dt$$

Then
$$F(x)= G \circ H(x)$$
and the FTC tells you what $G'(x)$ and $H'(x)$ are.